# JSON.NET. Navigate to JArray object from its children

Tags: c#, json, json.net

There's a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "men": [
    {
      "name": "Jordan",
      "phone": "333-333-33"
    },
    {
      "name": "Timothey",
      "phone": "444-444-44"
    }
  ],
  "women": [
    {
      "name": "Jordan",
      "phone": "111-111-11"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sasha",
      "phone": "222-222-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to find all people whose name starts with J and find whether this person is a man or a woman.

```
var jsonProps = jsonDoc.Descendants().Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)t).Name == prop);
var startsWithJ = jsonProps.Where(t => ((JProperty)t).Value.ToString().StartsWith("J"));

foreach (var person in startsWithJ)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Value<string>());
    Console.WriteLine(person.Parent.Parent.Value<string>());
}
```

The issue is that person.Parent.Parent is null and I expect it ot be JArray or at least JToken or at least some JToken so I can get its value.

**Update:**
I have like 100 types that use similar data structure. These collections (men, women) can be on any nesting level e.g. employees include men and women collection, or students include men and women collections. I can not create a strongly typed object for each of the types I have in my solution. Sometimes I need to remove objects from men/women collections and check whether the collection has any elements after this.

Comment: Why not use a strongly typed object?

Comment: I have like 100 types that use similar data structure. These collections (men, women) can be on any nesting level e.g. employees include men and women collection, or students include men and women collections. I can not create a strongly typed object for each of the types I have in my solution. Sometimes I need to remove objects from men/women collections and check whether the collection has any elements after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are operating on all the `name` properties that have a value that starts with "J", not the person objects that contain `name` properties that have a value that starts with "J".  So when you navigate upward, you aren't going far enough.  The `name` property's parent is the person object.  The person object's parent is the array, and the array's parent is the `men` (or `women`) `JProperty`.  (Also, to find out whether the array's containing property's name is "men" or "women", you'll need to get its `Name`, not its `Value`.)

So, if you change your code to the following, you should get the result you expect:

```
foreach (JProperty nameProp in startsWithJ)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameProp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(((JProperty)nameProp.Parent.Parent.Parent).Name);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7WxiF

Personally, I find it a little easier to work at the `JObject` level rather than the `JProperty` level.  Here is another way to get the same result:

```
var people = jsonDoc["men"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Union(jsonDoc["women"].Children<JObject>())
    .Where(obj => obj["name"] != null && obj["name"].ToString().StartsWith("J"));

foreach (JObject person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person["name"]);
    Console.WriteLine(((JProperty)person.Parent.Parent).Name);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzUOFT

If you are finding that you are always wanting to find the person's parent collection name in this way, you could go so far as to define an extension method:

```
public static class JHelper
{
    public static bool IsMale(this JObject person)
    {
        return ((JProperty)person.Parent.Parent).Name == "men";
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `IsMale()` on the `JObject`.  It makes the code a little more readable.

```
foreach (JObject person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + person["name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + (person.IsMale() ? "male" : "female"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to "how you query with LINQ to Json", but an approach i find easier using a strongly typed object.

By simply creating the following data structures (note the POCO's are decorated with `JsonProperty` which is a Json.NET attribute):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Person> Men { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Women { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Sex Sex { get; set }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Man,
    Women
}
```

Now, you can rather easily query what you need using LINQ to Objects:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (var male in rootObject.Men)
{
    male.Sex = Sex.Man;
}

foreach (var female in rootObject.Women)
{
    female.Sex = Sex.Women;
}

var startsWithJ = rootObject.Men.Concat(rootObject.Women)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("J",
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            .ToList();

foreach (var personStartsWithJ in startsWithJ)
{
    Console.WriteLine (personStartsWithJ.Name);
    Console.WriteLine (personStartsWithJ.Sex);
}
```